# Deleting logs file in Amazon s3 bucket according to created date

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, amazon-s3

How to delete the log files in Amazon s3 according to date.? I have log files in a logs folder folder inside my bucket.

```
  string sdate = datetime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
  string key = "logs/" + sdate + "*" ;
  AmazonS3 s3Client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client();

   DeleteObjectRequest delRequest = new DeleteObjectRequest()
  .WithBucketName(S3_Bucket_Name)
  .WithKey(key);

   DeleteObjectResponse res = s3Client.DeleteObject(delRequest);
```

I tried this but doesn't seem to work. I can delete individual files if I put the whole name in the key. But I want to delete all the log files created for a particular date.

Comment: You may want to consider the cost of deletion vs cost of storage. In my case, all my log file objects are less than 1KB in size. The cost of deletion of 1GB of such data is $0.4 (0.0004 for 1000 requessts. For 1 GB, there will be 1 Million files). Cost of storage of the data is $0.023 GB/month. Hence, it would take about 18 months worth of storage costs to recover the cost of deletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use S3's Object Lifecycle feature, specifically Object Expiration, to delete all objects under a given prefix and over a given age.  It's not instantaneous, but it beats have to make myriad individual requests.  To delete everything, just make the age small.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html